# ubuntu server 12.04 new installation does not boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, boot-failure, raid

I've just installed server 12.04 on a new machine.

It's got two network cards and two hard drives.

During installation it asked me if I wanted to make it RAID and I said ok to that.

Finally, it came to the packages options and I chose things like Samba, LAMP, etc.

And then it asked to reboot without the CD.

Did that and that's where the problem started. Nothing comes on the screen. Only a blinking cursor.

Has anyone experienced this problem? I'm guessing that it may be a RAID issue. Not sure.

Any thoughts please...

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same thing and solved it.  In the new bios there is a switch fro UEFI mode or not.  Disable UEFI.

Secondly my new i5 ASUS motherboard switched the hard drives.  It was trying to boot off of the second drive and not the bootable one.  Both were brand spanking new 1TB drived.  I reinstalled three times!

Get into BIOS
Disable UEFI
Go to boot menu and change the bootable drive. (NOT UEFI)